# How can I make an entire HTML page not fold?

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have a navigation bar and I do not want it to fold when the browser window becomes smaller. 
I found this article,[CSS-Tricks (Content Folding)](https://css-tricks.com/content-folding/). However, that only shows how to not fold one element. I want the **entire page** to not fold.

For example, I have a navigation bar, and when I shrink the browser window, the navigation Bar becomes 3 lines of navigation bars.

Comment: So you're asking how you can not have a navigation bar collapse when the viewport is shrunk to a narrower width? Why not simply just code code that behaviour into your website? Are you using a framework such as Bootstrap to achieve this collapse? ...Or are you talking about elements wrapping to the next line?

Comment: Could you please explain what *"not fold"* means for a page? What exactly should happen? It shouldn't allow scrolling even if the contents exceed the viewport height? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: i am not using a framework

Comment: not fold means not have the nav Bar become multiple rows when the window resizes

Comment: I dont know how to program this into my website, that is why i am asking it

Comment: Yes, anything is possible. Please add your code to the question, ideally providing a runnable [mcve]. Also, don't forget to specify **what** it is you want to happen with the content that should not *"fold"*. Btw, the correct term is *"wrap"*, not *"fold"*. Should the extra content be hidden? Should a scrollbar appear on the element so you could scroll to the elements which don't fit on screen width?